# Problems installing Sagemath

Tags: sagemath

In Ubuntu 20.04, when I type:

```
sudo apt-get install sagemath sagemath-jupyter sagemath-doc-en
```

I get:

```
Package sagemath is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.

E: Package 'sagemath' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package sagemath-jupyter
E: Unable to locate package sagemath-doc-en''
```

It appears the PPA is no longer maintained. Am I forced to go through the hassle of getting the binary and then all its dependencies or am I missing something obvious? I feel dumb.

After adding the universe repository and trying to install again I get:

```
E: Package 'sagemath' has no installation candidate
```

---

After adding the universe repository and trying to install again I get:

E: Package 'sagemath' has no installation candidate

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 focal : `sagemath` *is* in the repo → Please enable the **universe** repo. .... https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/sagemath

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Are you using some PPA? If so, remove the PPA and run `sudo apt update`. `sagemath` is already available from the official repo.

Comment: Please paste the output of `apt-cache policy sagemath` **in your question** (use the [edit] feature to edit your question).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than installing from the Ubuntu repositories, you may find it easier to go to `https://www.sagemath.org/download.html` and download the current version directly.  Installation is simple.  I'd suggest extracting the files to a directory `~/Sage`, `cd ~/Sage/SageMath` and then execute `./sage`

In a few minutes everything is set up.  Currently there are binaries for version 9.2, but 9.3 should show up fairly soon.

Comment: I do not see sagemath for Ubuntu 20.04 in the link you provided. Only for Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Just checked at https://mirror.rcg.sfu.ca/mirror/sage/linux/64bit/index.html.  I see a 9.4 binary for Ubuntu 20.04 posted 2021-08-31.